# Example of live site with trusted, signed but revoked certificate?

Tags: security-certificate

I'm drawing up some documentation for users with the intent on educating them on certificate revocation. I would like to include screen shots of browsers to demonstrate the user experience when encountering a revoked cert. The revocation can occur via either OCSP or CRL.

I've tried digging around CRLs, but they list the serial number of a certificate and don't provide a URL for me to try connecting.

Could someone provide a URL to a live site with a non-self-signed but revoked cert? Or perhaps there's a way to look up certs in a CRL and cross reference them to a URL?

Answer (score 2):

The revoked certificate of Mozilla Addons and its corresponding keyfiles are available in the wild. So you could test it yourself. For this experiment, you need to point the `addons.mozilla.org` domain to the IP address of your test server.

The private key file is 27 lines long and can be found at http://erratasec.blogspot.com/2011/03/verifying-comodo-hackers-key.html. The certifate can be downloaded from <strike>`http://www.multiupload.com/J9I8NFWPT0`</strike>.

If you're running a server on your local machine (localhost), change the hosts file, so `addons.mozilla.org` points to `127.0.0.1`. Use the key and certificate files above for your server.

Instructions using the `openssl` command on Ubuntu/Linux:

1. Put the keyfile in `moz.pem` and the certificate in `moz.crt`.
2. Add `127.0.0.1 addons.mozilla.org` to `/etc/hosts`
3. Start a HTTPS server using the `openssl s_server` command:

   ```
   sudo openssl s_server -cert moz.crt -key moz.pem -accept 443 -www
   ```
4. Go to your browser and take screenshots, copy text, etc.
5. When done, remove the entry from `/etc/hosts`.

An (tested) Linux shell script can be found at http://pastebin.com/DRE32SFR. Download it and execute it as root (required for binding to port 443 and editing `/etc/hosts`)

The next screenshots below are taken on Ubuntu 10.10 in Mozilla Firefox (without the patch) using the above instructions.

Firefox with CRL's enabled gives a warning:
[image: Firefox rejects the certificate using CRL's]

Opening Firefox with CRL checking disabled to simulate an unreachable CRL server opens the page without a gasp:
[image: Firefox opens the page successfully without error messages]

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to log-in to this website for a legitimate, large British insurance company and their certificate is invalid:

http://www.axa.co.uk/insurance/myaxaspace (12:02 GMT, 10th April 2011)

Firefox says that the certificate is "*not trusted because no issuer chain was provided*", but I'm not sure if this is what you're after.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed now.